# what is odata,json and soap?

Tags: json, soap, odata

hello friends
i am confused and unable to link the concepts in odata,json and soap?
how json protocol different from odata?

why do we need json when we already have odata?
why odata takes json format and atom format and in which situation?

Comment: OData and SOAP are protocols whereas JSON is a data format. Protocols might or might not enforce the use of specific data formats.

Comment: @Felix make that an answer and the question can be closed ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OData and SOAP are [***protocols***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol) whereas JSON is a data format (defines the syntax and semantics of data representation).

Protocols might or might not enforce the use of specific data formats (I think normally they do).

For example, OData uses JSON, SOAP uses XML.

---

Wikipedia is your friend if you want to read about this technologies in more detail.

Comment: so if i am using wcf ria services and i am using odata the the data format will be json?

Comment: what are the benefits of odata over soap? i mean why we prefer json data format over xml? why we use odata in ria services why not soap?

Comment: @iti: These are a lot of questions. I suggest you first read about the different protocols and then ask specific questions. But in general: JSON is more lightweight than XML and hence better suited for data transfer in the web where most of the additional features offered by XML are not needed.

Answer (score 2):

**SOAP** is a protocol specification for exchanging structured information in web

**Json** is a markup language like HTML , XML use to send data...

**OData** is  Web protocol for querying and updating data..